# HANA "create any" object privilege

Tags: sql, object, hana, privilege

I noticed a strange behaviour with "create any" privilege on a particular schema.
The official [help](https://help.sap.com/doc/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.02/en-US/2ab44c34eb5047a8899955bd1caae867.html) document says that "CREATE ANY" Authorizes all CREATE statements for the object.
However a user with **"CREATE ANY**" privilege on a schema is till able to perform *DROP, ALTER, SELECT, DELETE* operations on objects created by this user in the schema.
The user is **NOT** able to perform **DROP, ALTER, SELECT, DELETE** operations on objects created by **Other users** in the schema.

Any justification or reason for this behavior? 
How to identify the objects a particular user is allowed to **DROP, ALTER, SELECT, DELETE** ?

Thanks,
Anup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A schema is a namespace, not a privilege-space. Objects created by other users are **owned** by them, regardless of the schema they are created in.